# Can a bash function be used to fully escape any string (including nested single quotes)?

Tags: bash, nested, escaping, quotes

I know that there are a number of ways to manually escape nested quotes of the same kind.

Example

```
echo 'this single quote '"'"' is escaped.'
```

There are several more ways to do this that are documented well on StackOverflow already, but I'm trying to take that concept and apply it as a function to escape everything. I have been unsuccessful several times to find an all in one escaping solution for Bash (ex. I've looked for a string library that includes escaping with no luck).

Here's one of my attempts:

```
function quote() {
  printf '%s' "'${1//\'/\'"\'"\'}'"
}
```

The idea is that all single quotes will be replaced with the aforementioned escape style `'"'"'`. I've also tried doing the same thing using the escape style like so: `\'`. No luck.

Every response on this topic in my research that I've come across has made it sound like this isn't possible, but I'm not the type to accept that for an answer. To me, if you can echo a string like this: `'test \' test'`, then it should be expressible in a function too where the backslashes or otherwise are automatically added to escape the characters.

```
echo '~!@#$%^&*()_+`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\QWERTYUIOP{}|ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>?zxcvbnm,./'
```

As shown above, none of the basic keys on a traditional English keyboard need to be escaped, but nesting the same type of quotes within itself requires it.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Am I missing something obvious or is this really that difficult?

Comment: Can you include some examples of the inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: I'm using a script to run through a database of tags and collect the tags that I want to apply to my files. I've got a library to set those tags. The syntax is like this: `tag --set 'tag1,tag2,tag3'`. They are a comma separated list, but some of the tags have single quotes in them and some of them have double quotes. Ex. `Tom's_Shoes` could be one tag, while `The_"best"` could be another tag. Because of this, I can't just use straight single quotes or straight double quotes without escaping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to mimic the shell quoting, properly quoting the variables should be enough.

```
#! /bin/bash

tag () {
    echo Setting tags to "$2".
}

while read tags ; do
    tag --set "$tags"
done  <<EOF
tag1,tag2,tag3
Tom's_Shoes
The_"best"
EOF
```

Comment: I swear sometimes I make things too difficult. I really appreciate you taking the time to share this. It makes me want to get a better handle on Bash. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the tags are in variables or an array and you use proper quoting, you should't need to do any extra escaping. See @choroba's answer.

But there are times when you need it and this will do the trick:

```
printf -v my_var '%q' "$myvar"
```

which replaces the contents of `my_var` with an shell-escaped version.